# Run-time error '13' VBA Macro Excel

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I created this macro and I get a Run-time error '13' at the line

```
Set objDomAttribute = objDomElement3.Attributes.setNamedItem(objDomDoc.createAttribute("Name4"))
```

My Excel file has 2727 rows. I tested it for fewer rows and it works perfectly, but for 2727 it doesn't work. What should I do for solving that?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeXMLWithDom() 

Dim Q As String 
Q = Chr$(34) 

Dim objDomDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60 

objDomDoc.LoadXML ("<?xml version=" & Q & "1.0" & Q & "encoding=" & Q & "utf-8" & Q & "?>") 

Dim objDomElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement 
Dim objDomAttribute As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute 
Dim nodeSet As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList 

Set objDomElement = objDomDoc.createElement("Containers") 
Set objDomElement = objDomDoc.appendChild(objDomElement) 

 'finding the amount of rows in the excel
Dim numofrows As Long 
numofrows = Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Range("E1").Offset(Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row 

Dim iRow As Integer 

Dim Value11 As Variant 
Dim Value12 As Variant 
Dim Value13 As Variant 

Dim objDomElement1 As Variant
Dim objDomElement2 As Variant
Dim objDomElement3 As Variant

For iRow = 10 To (numofrows + 1) 

    If Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow - 1, 5) = Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow, 5) Then 
        Value11 = Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow - 1, 11).Value & ", " & Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow, 11).Value 
        Value12 = Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow - 1, 12).Value & ", " & Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow, 12).Value 
        Value13 = Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow - 1, 13).Value & ", " & Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow, 13).Value 
    Else 
        Value11 = Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow, 11).Value 
        Value12 = Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow, 12).Value 
        Value13 = Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow, 13).Value 
    End If 

    If Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow, 5) <> Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow + 1, 5) And Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow, 3) <> "" And Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow, 5) <> "" Then 

        Set objDomElement1 = objDomElement.appendChild(objDomDoc.createElement("Data")) 
        Set objDomAttribute = objDomElement1.Attributes.setNamedItem(objDomDoc.createAttribute("Relevant")) 
        objDomElement1.Attributes.getNamedItem("Relevant").Text = "True" 

        Set objDomElement2 = objDomElement1.appendChild(objDomDoc.createElement("Info")) 

        Set objDomElement3 = objDomElement2.appendChild(objDomDoc.createElement("Part")) 
        Set objDomAttribute = objDomElement3.Attributes.setNamedItem(objDomDoc.createAttribute("Name1")) 
        Set objDomAttribute = objDomElement3.Attributes.setNamedItem(objDomDoc.createAttribute("Name2")) 
        Set objDomAttribute = objDomElement3.Attributes.setNamedItem(objDomDoc.createAttribute("Name3")) 
        Set objDomAttribute = objDomElement3.Attributes.setNamedItem(objDomDoc.createAttribute("Name4")) 

        objDomElement3.Attributes.getNamedItem("Name1").Text = Trim$(Worksheets("EXAMPLE").Cells(iRow, 5).Value) 
        objDomElement3.Attributes.getNamedItem("Name2").Text = Value11 
        objDomElement3.Attributes.getNamedItem("Name3").Text = Value12 
        objDomElement3.Attributes.getNamedItem("Name4").Text = Value13 

    End If 
Next iRow 

objDomDoc.Save ("c:\Example.xml") 
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a "Type mismatch" error. Declaring *all* of your variables using `Dim` will help you locate the cause of this error. You haven't declared `objDomElement3`, for instance. You should force yourself to do this for all variables always by writing `Option Explicit` at the very top of your module.

Comment: Mr. Corbett, I listened to your advice, I added the Option Explicit, I declared the objDomElements but still I have the same error at the same line.

Comment: When you step through your code in debug mode, look at the Locals window. What is the type of all of the variables involved in that line? Are they as expected?

Comment: For the Value13 it says Value: Error 2015 and Type: Variant/Error I don't know if you mean that because I'm new in coding. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that `Value13` in the Locals window shows as `Value: Error 2015` and `Type: Variant/Error`. Well, okay, keep on investigating... Where does `Value13` come from? Look in your Excel sheet on that line. I bet you'll find a `#VALUE!` error there.

So it's a problem in your input data, not your code. Fix that and your problem will go away.

Comment: Mr. Corbett, thank you vey much for your help. I will keep in mind your advice about declaring everything! I found the solution but still I don't get it. I just declared the Value13 as String and not Variant. Variant is used for any type of value. Why it didn't work then? :)

Comment: Because you're implicitly trying to store an `Error` value into a `String` type variable. Implicit casting to `String` works for some data types but not for all data types and in particular not for `Error`. If you want, you can user `CStr()` to do the casting explicitly, but isn't it better to just remove the error from your input data... P.S. Did you see my last comment to your question above?